# Custom Angular library converts const to declared interface on build

Tags: angular, npm-package, ng-packagr, ng-build

I'm creating a library of angular components using ng-packagr. I have a set of static data I want included so my apps have access to same set of data. I have a this, as an example, in a `bookList.ts` file:

```
export const bookList = {
  CAT: { title: 'Cat Book' },
  DOG: { title: 'Dog Book' },
  BIRD: { title: 'Bird Book' }
}
```

When I run `ng build` it's output as

```
export declare const bookList = {
      CAT: { title: string },
      DOG: { title: string },
      BIRD: { title: string }
    }
```

How can I include the data in my package and avoid the conversion?